# Clarification about a Convergence in Probability example proof

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $U \sim \mathrm{Uniform}[0,1]$.

$$
X_n= \begin{cases}
     3 & U \leq \frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{n} \\
     8 & \text{otherwise}
     \end{cases}    
$$

$$
Y = \begin{cases}
     3 & U \leq \frac{2}{3} \\
     8 & \text{otherwise}
     \end{cases}
$$

We have for $\epsilon > 0:$

$$ X_n = Y \text{ unless } \frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{n} <U \leq\frac{2}{3}$$

$$P(\mid X_n-Y\mid \;\geq \epsilon) \leq P(X_n \neq Y)$$

$$= P(\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{n} < U \leq \frac{2}{3})$$ 
$$=\frac{1}{n}$$

Hence, $P(|X_n-Y| \geq \epsilon) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for all $\epsilon > 0$
and the sequence $\{X_n\}$ converges in probability to $Y.$

I don't understand why: $P(|X_n-Y| \geq \epsilon) \leq P(X_n \neq Y)$
Could someone explain?

Comment: To have $|X_n-Y| \geq \epsilon$ you certainly must have $X_n \neq Y$. When $\epsilon<5$ these are actually the same in this case (why?)

Comment: @Ian, $P(X_n \neq Y) = P(\mid X_n - Y \mid \; \geq \; \epsilon) + P(0 \;<\; \mid X_n - Y \mid \; < \; \epsilon)$.   Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because both $X_n$ and $Y$ **only** take values from a set of two points $\{3, 8\}$, which means given any positive $\epsilon \in (0, 5]$, the set 
\begin{align}
\{\omega: |X_n(\omega) - Y(\omega)| \geq \epsilon\} & = \{\omega: X_n(\omega) = 8, Y(\omega) = 3\} \cup \{\omega: X_n(\omega) = 3, Y(\omega) = 8\} \\
& = \{\omega: X_n(\omega) \neq Y(\omega)\}.
\end{align}

And if $\epsilon > 5$, then
$$\{\omega: |X_n(\omega) - Y(\omega)| \geq \epsilon\} = \varnothing.$$

So in either case, we have $P[|X_n - Y| \geq \epsilon] \leq P[X_n \neq Y]$.